# Asp.net MVC 4 API and Knockout.js: Generate Knockout.js models

Tags: asp.net-mvc, knockout.js

I'd like to have my knockout.js classes generated from my AspNet API controller and model classes.

I've googled quite a bit, but it looks as if I'll have to build it myself.

Any pointers to existing tools/code that will make this easier are appreciated!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Look at using [Knockout.mapping](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/plugins-mapping.html).  This converts the json received from your controller automatically into view models complete with observables.

Comment: great tip! hadn't seen that yet. So before I go down the generation path, I'll definitively give this a thorough try.